# How can i get data from two CSV files to show one on graph for comparrison?

Tags: python, csv

ive been trying to get data from two seperate CSV files to show on one graph so that visual comparrison of the data can be done, i can get both results to print once the script has run but i cant get that data to show on the graph, im sure im missing something here but ive been stuck on this for a while. Here is the source code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

df1 = pd.read_csv(r'/home/morgankemp/Downloads/Data2.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(r'/home/morgankemp/Downloads/Data.csv')
print (df)
print(df1)

X = list(df.iloc[:, 0])
Y = list(df.iloc[:, 1])

plt.scatter(X, Y, color='b')
plt.title("Levels of Methane (CH4) Emissions (Tonnes) From Denmark 2010 - 2019")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.ylabel("Number of Tonnes")

plt.show()
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, thanks.

Output of code: [image]

Graph only showing one set of results:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following kind of approach to loop over each file and colour combination:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

data = [
    [r'/home/morgankemp/Downloads/Data.csv', 'b'], 
    [r'/home/morgankemp/Downloads/Data2.csv', 'g']
]

for filename, colour in data:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    X = list(df.iloc[:, 0])
    Y = list(df.iloc[:, 1])
    plt.scatter(X, Y, color=colour)

plt.title("Levels of Methane (CH4) Emissions (Tonnes) From Denmark 2010 - 2019")
plt.xlabel("Years")
plt.ylabel("Number of Tonnes")

plt.show()
```

Without the data in text format it is difficult to test.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
plt.scatter(df1['Year'],df1['Long header here'])
plt.scatter(df2['Year'],df2['Long header here'])
plt.show()
```